# global name is not defined, how should I import?

Tags: python

I encountered this error `global name ** is not defined` in my code, here below is a minimal example,

test1.py

```
 def f():
   print 'inside f()'
   g()
   return
```

test2.py

```
 def g():
   print 'inside g()'

 from test1 import f
 f()
```

When I run `python test2.py` in the terminal, I have the error `NameError: global name 'g' is not defined`, how should I import `test1` to avoid this error?

Comment: If you use `g` in `test1`, you need to import `g` in `test1`.

Comment: @BrenBarn, if I import `g` in `test1`, then import `f` in `test2`, this will result in a circular importing, will that be a problem?

Comment: Python will Do The Right Thing if you have circular imports, but mutual imports are a code smell of bad thinking. If there is a dependency as your have shown they belong in the same module/namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to separate the call to `f()` to a different file, then you can do something like this:

test1.py

```py
from test2 import g

def f():
  print 'inside f()'
  g()
  return
```

test2.py

```py
def g():
  print 'inside g()'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from test1 import f
  f()
```

This way, the call to `f()` in test2 will only run if it's the script executed:

```
$ python test2.py
inside f()
inside g()
```